# Discarding apples - why is my reasoning wrong?

Tags: probability

There are two types of apples - red and green. The ratio of red to green is $4:1$. They are mixed together before they are boxed. There is $\frac{1}{50}$ chance that a green apple is discarded, and $\frac{1}{100}$ chance that a red apple is discarded. What is the probability that an apple selected will be discarded?

**Attempt**: I have

Green apple discarded OR red apple discarded

$\frac{4}{5}\frac{1}{50}$ + $\frac{1}{5}\frac{1}{100}$

**Question**: Why is this incorrect? It seems I have to multiply by $\frac{2}{3}$ to get the correct answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to have confused red and green and your calculation should have been $$\frac{4}{5}\frac{1}{100}+\frac{1}{5}\frac{1}{50}=\frac{3}{250}$$

As a check, suppose you had $1000$ apples

- You would expect to have $800$ red apples and $200$ green apples
- You would expect to discard $8$ red apples and $4$ green apples
- So you would expect to discard $12$ apples, $\frac{12}{1000}=\frac{3}{250}$ of the total

Comment: Gosh that is embarrassing. You are right

Comment: @user71207. Your original answer was why we multiply by $\frac{2}{3}$, was not it?

Comment: sorry what do you mean by that?

Comment: @user71207. "It seems I have to multiply by $\frac{2}{3}$ to get the correct answer"? What do you mean by this statement please?

Comment: Oh I knew that I had to multiply by 2/3 but I wasn't sure why. Multiplying by 2/3 would not make any logical sense given what I had though

Comment: @Avra I think he means the ratio between the correct answer and his (incorrect) one is $\frac 23$. He was "off" by a factor of $\frac 23$. Nothing special in that fraction, just his observation.

Comment: @Avra The original question had $\frac{4}{5}\frac{1}{50}+\frac{1}{5}\frac{1}{100} =\frac{9}{500}$ due to a small error.  The correct answer is $\frac23$ of this but the $\frac23$ is not special here

Comment: @Henry. Thank you.

Comment: @Deepak. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Haven't you mixed it up a bit?

Let $P(G)$ be probability of a green apple being selected and $P(R)$ be probability of a red apple being selected.

Let $P(D|G)$ be probability of discard if green apple and $P(D|R)$ be probability of discard if red apple.

Probability of an apple being discarded $P(D) = P(G)\cdot P(D|G) + P(R)\cdot P(D|R) = \frac 15 \frac 1{50} + \frac 45 \cdot \frac 1{100} = \frac 3{250}$

Comment: Yes, I misread the question